# Wrong Key Size Exception when decrypt plain text using RSA_Decrypted 3DES KEY

Tags: exception, key, rsa, 3des

I am trying to implement a hybrid cryptosystem that:

1. encrypts text using 3DES and ecnryptes the 3DES key using RSA encryption algorithm
2. Decrypted RSA-encrypted 3DES key and then use it to decrypt the cipher text to get retrive the encrypted plaintext

It throws an exception of:

> Invalid Key Size Exception

How can I fix the code?

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;


import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

public class Hybrid_Implementation_V2 {

//3DES_Encryption Algorithm Required Variables
private byte[] DES_Key;
private SecretKeyFactory keyfactory;
private DESedeKeySpec spec;
private Key deskey;
private int DES_Key_Length;
private byte[] data;
private Cipher cipher;
private String CipherText;
private byte [] CIPHERText;

//RSA
private KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
private KeyPair pair;
private PrivateKey privateKey;
private PublicKey publicKey;
private final Cipher RSA_cipher;

Hybrid_Implementation_V2() throws InvalidKeyException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException
{
    this.keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    this.keyGen.initialize(1024);
    this.RSA_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    DES_Key_Generator();
    RSA_Key_Generation();
}

                //KEY Generation Mechanism
//3DES Key Generation
private void DES_Key_Generator() throws InvalidKeyException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String key = rnd.toString();

    DES_Key = key.getBytes();
    spec = new DESedeKeySpec(DES_Key);
    keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede");
    deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
}

//RSA Public - Private Key Generation
private void RSA_create_Key()
{
    this.pair = this.keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    this.privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
this.publicKey = pair.getPublic();
}

public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() 
    {
    return this.privateKey;
}

public PublicKey getPublicKey() 
    {
    return this.publicKey;
}

    public void RSA_Key_Generation(){RSA_create_Key();}



// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html

public PrivateKey getPrivate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
InvalidKeySpecException
    {
    byte[] keyBytes = getPrivateKey().getEncoded();
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}

// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html
public PublicKey getPublic() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
InvalidKeySpecException
    {
    byte[] keyBytes = getPublicKey().getEncoded();
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
    public String RSA_encryptText(String msg) throws 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, 
UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, 
BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException {
 PrivateKey key = getPrivate(); 
        this.RSA_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(RSA_cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

public String RSA_decryptText(String msg)throws InvalidKeyException, 
UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, 
BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    PublicKey key = getPublic();
        this.RSA_cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    return new String(RSA_cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(msg)), "UTF-8");
}
              //Hybrid Encryption Mechanism
//Encryption Function Caller
private String encryption(String plaintext) throws InvalidKeyException, 
IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, 
InvalidKeySpecException
{
    String cipher_text = DES_Encryption(plaintext);
    String RSA_DESKey = RSA_encryptText(DES_Key.toString());
    DES_Key_Length = RSA_DESKey.length();
    CipherText ="";
    CipherText = new 
StringBuilder().append(RSA_DESKey).append(cipher_text).toString();
    return CipherText;
}

//3DES Encryption
 private String DES_Encryption(String plaintext) throws InvalidKeyException, 
IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    data = plaintext.getBytes();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deskey);
    CIPHERText = cipher.doFinal(data);
    StringBuilder hexCiphertext = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<CIPHERText.length; i++)
    {
        int v = CIPHERText[i] & 0xff;
        v+=0x100;
        String temp = Integer.toString(v,16);
        hexCiphertext.append(temp).substring(1);
    }
    return hexCiphertext.toString();
}

                   //Hybrid Decryption Mechanism
 //Decryption Function Caller
 private String decryption(String encrypted_text) throws 
InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException, IllegalBlockSizeException, 
BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
NoSuchPaddingException
{
    StringBuilder encryptedkey = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder cipheredtext = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < DES_Key_Length; i++)    //Extraction of Encrypted 
3DES Key
        encryptedkey.append (encrypted_text.charAt(i));
    for(int j = DES_Key_Length ; j< encrypted_text.length() ; j++)      
//Extraction of Ciphered Text
        cipheredtext.append (encrypted_text.charAt(j));
    String temp = RSA_decryptText(encryptedkey.toString());
    byte [] DES_KEY = temp.getBytes();
    String plaintext = 
DES_Decryption(DES_KEY,cipheredtext.toString().getBytes());
       return plaintext;
}


 //3DES Decryption
private String DES_Decryption(byte [] key, byte [] encrypted_text) throws 
InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, 
InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException
{

    Key deskey;
    DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(key);
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede");
    deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,deskey);
    byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(encrypted_text);
    StringBuilder decrypttext= new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++)
        decrypttext.append((char) plaintext[i]);
    return decrypttext.toString();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.security.InvalidKeyException
 * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
 * @throws javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
 * @throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, 
IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException 
{

    String plaintext;
    Hybrid_Implementation_V2 hi = new Hybrid_Implementation_V2 ();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Text = ");
    plaintext = sc.nextLine();
    String encrypted_text = hi.encryption(plaintext);
    String decrypted_text = hi.decryption(encrypted_text);
    System.out.println("Plain Text Entered = "+plaintext);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Text = "+encrypted_text);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Text = "+decrypted_text);

}

}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: There are numerous elementary mistakes, too numerous to list. You can't be a programmer without learning to use a debugger, so that should be your first step.

Comment: Sure **halfer** and **James K Polk**  thanks for the comments helped alot